# Repositioning textview with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm struggling with a strange issue... I've set everything up using Storyboard.
Depending on the size of text contents an uitextview has, I have to programmatically resize & reposition it.  However, it seems like it's not repositioning as I wish :(

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //ansContent is connected to the uitextview via IBOutlet
    ansContent.frame = CGRectMake(27, 90, 270, 10000);
    ansContent.text = @"very very long text here";
}
```

It seems like the changing the text works... not the frame :S  What is wrong with it?
All I did in Storyboard was to drag & drop an uitextview and connect it to ansContent.

Comment: Disable Auto Layout and check.

Comment: OMG, YOU Sir. You rock. Post your answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the auto layout option in storyboard. In your case, the autolayout is preventing it from displaying it in proper location. Once you have disabled it, you can set the frame programmatically.